# I am not sure why not all of my numbers that are overlapping are not being appended to the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

I am writing a file overlap function using binary search that takes two arguments: longestFile and shorterFile. I want to see if two files have the same numbers and if they do, it will append that number to an empty list. These are the two lists I am using for the program: [This is the first file that we need to use](http://www.practicepython.org/assets/primenumbers.txt) and [This is the second file that we need to use](http://www.practicepython.org/assets/happynumbers.txt).

```
def longestFile(firstFile, secondFile):
   if len(firstFile)>len(secondFile):
      return firstFile
   else:
      return secondFile

def shortestFile(firstFile, secondFile):
   if len(firstFile) < len(secondFile):
      return firstFile
   else:
      return secondFile

def middleNumber(theLongestFile):
   return theLongestFile[len(theLongestFile)//2]

def fileOverlap(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile):
   lstMatchingNums = []
   lstLongerFile = longestFile(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile)
   lstShortestFile = shortestFile(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile)
   for eachLines in range(len(lstShortestFile)):
       lstLongerFile = longestFile(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile)
       for eachLine in range(len(lstLongerFile)):
          if lstShortestFile[eachLines] == middleNumber(lstLongerFile):
              lstMatchingNums.append(lstShortestFile[eachLines])
              break
          elif lstShortestFile[eachLines] < middleNumber(lstLongerFile):
             lstLongerFile = lstLongerFile[0:(len(lstLongerFile)//2)+1]
             if len(lstLongerFile) <= 2 and lstLongerFile[0] == lstShortestFile[eachLines]:
                 lstMatchingNums.append(lstShortestFile[eachLines])
                 break
             elif middleNumber(lstLongerFile) != lstShortestFile[eachLines] and len(lstLongerFile) <=2:
                 break
          elif lstShortestFile[eachLines] > middleNumber(lstLongerFile):
              lstLongerFile = lstLongerFile[(len(lstLongerFile)//2):]
              if len(lstLongerFile) <= 2 and lstLongerFile[0] == lstShortestFile[eachLines]:
                 lstMatchingNums.append(lstShortestFile[eachLines])
                 break
              elif middleNumber(lstLongerFile) != lstShortestFile[eachLines] and len(lstLongerFile) <= 2:
                 break
  return lstMatchingNums

lstHappyNums = open('happynumbs.txt','r')
lstReadingHappyLines = lstHappyNums.readlines()
lstHappyNums.close()
lstPrimeNumsFile = open('primenumbers.txt', 'r')
lstReadingPrimeLines = lstPrimeNumsFile.readlines()
print(fileOverlap(lstReadingHappyLines,  lstReadingPrimeLines))
```

If I ran this program, I would get: `['19\n', '193\n', '239\n', '263\n', '293\n', '313\n', '331\n', '367\n', '379\n', '383\n', '397\n', '487\n', '563\n', '617\n', '653\n', '673\n', '683\n', '709\n', '739\n', '761\n', '881\n', '907\n', '937\n']` and I am not sure why I am getting parts of the numbers that overlap and not all of them. I am not sure why my binary search isn't working for this.

Comment: Your files are sorted numerically, but you're comparing them as strings. You need to convert the lines to numbers.

Comment: E.g. `10 > 2` but `'10' < '2'`

Comment: @Barmar so I should put int in front of the lstShortestFile?

Comment: You should do it when you create the lists `lstReadingHappyLines` and `lstReadingPrimeLines`. Remove the newlines and call `int()` on each element.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022716/converting-a-list-of-numbers-in-a-text-file-to-integers